# how to reduce SSL handshake time - localhost/self signed cert

Tags: https, security-certificate

We have one .net exe running on local machine and browser make one API to that running service with https://localhost:45235/getInfo. Actual getInfo API returns response in < 1 sec. But when browser makes call to same API it takes > 4 secs.

When debugged observed that In browser dev tools-> network tabs -> Initial connection SSL takes almost ~ 3secs.

Would like to understand why SSL handshake takes ~3 secs and any way with which this time can be reduced?

Note: To make this https call locally we have self signed certificate on local machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any difference between browsers?

Comment: Why are you running https rather then http on localhost?

Comment: There is no difference of delay in browsers. Every browsers same SSL handshake time

Comment: I dont remember exactly what made this decision to make it https. May be we have to revisit this aspect.

Comment: is there anything we an do to reduce this SSL handshake time?

Comment: localhost http call gets blocked by antivirus installed on that machine, for security purpose https is made.